# Update function not working in access form

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access-2007, userform

```
**CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE SStable" & _
    "SET [Status of review]='" & Me.Revstats.Value & "'" & _
    ", [Reviewer]='" & Me.Reviewersname.Value & "'" & _
    ", [Assessment]='" & Me.Assessments.Value & "'" & _
    ", [Review Comments]='" & Me.Review_Comments.Value & "'" & _
    ", [RID]='" & Me.RID23.Value & "'" & _
    " WHERE (([RIT] = '" & Me.Reviewspending.Value & "') AND [Processed]= '" & Me.CBOSSP.Value & "';"**
```

The code is showing correct results however the same is not getting updated in table

Comment: There is a space already

Comment: & _ it is there in first line

Comment: That's to break the code to the next line, not to leave a space in the string.

Comment: Im unsure where to provide space, can you modify and send it

Comment: I tried providing space now ... in Immediate window it shows argument not optional

Comment: I have tried it but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try with these corrections:

```vb
CurrentDb.Execute _   
    "UPDATE SStable " & _
    "SET [Status of review]='" & Me.Revstats.Value & "'" & _
    ", [Reviewer]='" & Me.Reviewersname.Value & "'" & _
    ", [Assessment]='" & Me.Assessments.Value & "'" & _
    ", [Review Comments]='" & Me.Review_Comments.Value & "'" & _
    ", [RID]='" & Me.RID23.Value & "' " & _
    "WHERE [RIT] = '" & Me.Reviewspending.Value & "' AND [Processed] = '" & Me.CBOSSP.Value & "';"
```

> Immediate window .. shows argument not optional

That indicates a missing or misspelled table or field name.